# Telegram madelineproto in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I need to add the [Telegram madelineproto library](https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/) to my Laravel project. How can I do it via composer and How can I call it in my controllers

Answer (score 5):

```
composer require danog/madelineproto
```

https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/INSTALLATION.html#composer-from-existing-project

Register `\danog\MadelineProto\API` class to [Laravel Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container)

Or use ready wrapper

https://github.com/setiawanhu/laravel-madeline-proto

Answer (score 0):

You can't add it via composer.
https://packagist.org/packages/danog/madelineproto
It's not a package. It's whole project.

If you look at https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/blob/master/composer.json
You will see it's not a package.

```
{
    "name": "danog/madelineproto",
    "description": "PHP implementation of telegram's MTProto protocol.",
    "type": "project",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for faster code, use these steps:

### Step 1:

[download](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto) the `danog/MadelineProto` as a zip file, export the content of the zip file on a folder named 'lib/MadelineProto-master',

### Step 2:

use terminal to compose the `MadelineProto` venders

```
cd lib/MadelineProto-master
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

`--ignore-platform-reqs` is needed to ignore the PHP version and so on.
the composer will download all the vender on `lib/MadelineProto-master/vendor`

### Step 3:

on your controller call the project lib like this:

```php
require_once '../lib/MadelineProto-master/vendor/autoload.php';

//*/
class TelegramController extends Controller
{

    private function sendMessage()
    {

        $settings['app_info']['api_id'] = '##';
        $settings['app_info']['api_hash'] = '####';


        $MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline', $settings);

        $MadelineProto->start();

        $me = $MadelineProto->getSelf();

        if (!$me['bot']) {

            $sendMessage =  $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage([
                'peer' => '@mansourcodes',
                'message' => "Hi! <3"
            ]);

        }

    }
}
```

### Slow Solution:

this solution will take 3-4s per call:

```php
if (!file_exists('madeline/madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline/madeline.php');
}
require_once 'madeline/madeline.php';

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
// ....
```

Comment: Tested on Laravel 8 localy